# Loading a linux dynamic library (.so) in C# on Windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows, shared-libraries, swig

I am using swig to generate a C# wrapper to my code. But then I also need to link the dynamic library, which is a Linux .so file. Is it possible to do this from C#?

Thanks

Edit: using a .so file on Windows.

Comment: Linking a .so on Win is certainly strange. Why can't you use a .dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this. You need to create a native Windows version of all your native code (the so itself, plus all dependencies).

Other options include writing all your code on Linux, if possible, including the C# portion (using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com)). Or creating some sort of client/server setup, where your native code remains on Linux (as a server application) and your C# code goes on the Windows-client. If that is a viable solution for you is hard to tell without further details.

Answer (score 0):

This [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072961/calling-unix-and-linuxshared-object-file-so-from-c-sharp) seems to have some answers for Linux, are you trying to do this in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

It's more than likely that your shared library will have been compiled to use linux command calls.

The only possible way to use linux .so files in a "windows" app would be to compile it (your app) using cygwin, but that way would make your windows app a posix app which means it would have to fire cygwin up everytime it runs.